# How to setup ActiveStorage to allow both public and private attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

In my Rails app, I have various models requiring uploads using ActiveStorage. Some models require signed, single use urls, and other models require public urls that do not expire.

I haven't see any options on how to differentiate between them on a per model basis.

Is this possible with ActiveStorage, or is it all or nothing regarding public and private uploads?

Comment: This is not a feature of ActiveStorage. If you want to restrict access to the actual file URL you need to serve it through Rails.

Comment: I will be serving all my files from rails. The problem is that I can't upload avatars for users, because they have an expiration of 5 minutes, and therefore, won't work in emails that are sent out by the system and the images will be broken when they expire. I also have some private uploads that work well with the default ActiveStorage config. Is there a way to remove the expiry from the upload? So that a link that's generated from rails can be accessed whenever the user loads an email?

Answer (score 1):

Active Storage doesn't seem to support permanent, non-expiring URLs，maybe you can configure your own controller action which redirects to the attachment URL.

eg

```
def show
  redirect_to or send_data
end
```

Then use the url pointed to this action in the place you want.